# Regular expression that matches only if there is exactly one occurrence

Tags: regex

I wrote this regex

`(<b>)\b[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{4,15}</b>`

But I would like that the match is triggered only if there is exactly one occurrence, so I thought I need to do this

`((<b>)\b[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{4,15}</b>){1}`

But it doesn't seem to work. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which tool or language are you using?

Comment: Try `(<b>)\b[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{4,15}</b>.*`

Comment: What you need to do is not just match one occurrence, but make sure there are no other occurrences  in the string you're trying to match. You can do this with lookaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a negative lookahead to assert that a second match does not occur:

```
^(?!.*\b[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{4,15}\b.*\b[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{4,15}\b).*\b[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{4,15}\b.*$
```

This is a verbose regex, and very hard to read.  Let's say you wanted to match strings in which the word `BAT` occurred once and only once.  We could write:

```
^(?!.*\bBAT\b.*\bBAT\b).*\bBAT\b.*$
```